# Two-part question with "or"

Tags: conjunctions, word-order, questions, parallelism

> I mean do we have a full control on our destiny or uncontrollable factors are involved in shaping our future?

In the question above including the conjunction 'or', did it follow the structure of a question?

Comment: I would rephrase it as "I mean, do we have full control of our destiny, or are uncontrollable factors involved in shaping our future?" Be aware this question is likely to be closed because proofreading questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @robusto thank you. it's about the grammar of making questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "or" part is correct, but the rest of the grammar is bad.

> ... do we have full control of our destiny or are uncontrollable factors involved in shaping...

Each part of the question separated by the "or" should be grammatically correct when read separately.

Comment: Also as an issue of good *style* if you have two parallel arguments you should use the same structure for both, "Do we have full control of our destiny, or do uncontrollable factors shape our future?"  To be clear, the other way isn't *wrong*, but good style often makes the sentence easier to parse.